# getting [] when set a useState interface array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I'm trying to set a useState variable using an interface inside a `createContext`. The goal is fetch some data inside `someArray` and added into a useState. The following code uses react with typescript:

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export interface exportedInterface {
  stateData: NftsData[];
  fetchUnstakedNFTs: () => void;
}

interface Data {
  dataString: string,
  dataNumber: number,
}

export const customContext = createContext<exportedInterface>();

const CustomContext: FC = ({ children = null as any }) => {
  const [stateData, setStateData] = useState<Data[]>([]);
  let listDataArray: Data[] = [];

  export const fetchSomeArray = async () => {
    for (let item of someArray) {
      await fetch(item.url)
        .then(resp =>
          resp.json()
        ).then((json) => {
          const listData: Data = {  
            {
              dataString: json.stringData,
              dataNumber: json.numberData
            }
          listDataArray.push(listData)
        }
    }
    setStateData(listDataArray) // this part doesn't work
  }

  console.log('stateData: ', stateData)

  return (
    <CustomContext.Provider
      value={{
        stateData,
        fetchUnstakedNFTs,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CustomContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Then I create the context with the folowing file:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { CustomContext } from 'aboveFile';

export const useCustomContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(CustomContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      'CustomContext undefined'
    );
  }
  return context;
};
```

Finally in other component I import the `CustomContext` and run `fetchSomeArray()` using `useEffect` as in the following code:

```
import { useCustomContext } from 'aboveFile';

export default function App() {
  const { fetchSomeArray } = useCustomContext();
  useEffect(() => { fetchSomeArray() }, [])

  return (
   ...
  )
}
```

then I obtain the following output:

```
stateData: [] // HERE IS THE ISSUE
```

I don't know why useState `setStateData` is not working since `stateData` value is `[]`

I tried to use `await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1500));` before `console.log('stateData: ', stateData)` to give it time to update the state of `stateData` and still getting `[]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: Are you using `useState()` outside of a component ? It is not meant for that

Comment: also the `listData.push` closing brackets are the wrong way around.

Comment: You are mutating state on subsequent re-renders by calling `push` on `listData` -- which is now a pointer to the same array as `stateData`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @HappyDev I can't find the answer where you recommend, it is the same problem but in different scenarios.

Comment: @OneQ I'm inside a component (now I clarify it).

Comment: @Linda Paiste I tried your proposal without solving the issue (this is updated in the question)

Comment: That can't be the actual component, right? Because you would get an infinite loop ("too many re renders") if you are calling `setStateData` at the top-level like that.

Comment: @Linda Paiste You are right, I'm actually parsing an array to save its values in a useState (I updated the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is produced because the `useState` set method is not reflecting a change immediately as it is expained in this post [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

When I console.log the value of `stateData` after calling `useEffect` the value is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The following be a working version of what you were trying to do

```
import "./styles.css";

import { useState } from "react";

interface Data {
  dataString: string;
  dataNumber: number;
}

export default function App() {
  const [stateData, setStateData] = useState<Data[]>([]);

  const addToData = () => {
    setStateData((prev) => [
      ...prev,
      {
        dataString: "data",
        dataNumber: 2
      }
    ]);
  };

  console.log("stateData: ", stateData);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Title Text</h1>
      <h2>Subtitle text</h2>
      <button onClick={addToData}>Press ME</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried your proposals and still getting `[]` (this is updated in the question)

Comment: were you clicking the button that was included in the answer i gave?

Comment: also you can't call setState inside of the component like that, as it causes a re-render causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly update your state, you can use `useEffect` like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchSomeArray()
  }, []);
```

And you can remove the export of the function `fetchSomeArray`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called FetchSomeDataArray() function anywhere that's why your state is still an empty array. If you want it to be called before rendering it then wrap this in the **UseEffect** hook with an empty dependency list.

or You can trigger this function on any event like button clicking, hovering etc.

Here is code for how you can use useEffect hook:

```
useEffect( async () => {
    // fetch some data function declaration
    const fetchSomeDataArray = async () => { .... };
    // function call
    await fetchSomeDataArray();
},[])
```